# Excel formula to rearrange LastName, Firstname MiddleInitial to FirstName Lastname

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need some help with a formula to rearrange names. I've found lots of formulas that work in some cases, but none that can handle all of the cases I encounter.

Briefly, here is the list of names, and the desired output:

```
Original names              Desired Output
John, James J               James John
Junior, Lake                Lake Junior
Mitchel, Fields M           Fields Mitchel
Rothschild Jr., Michael K   Michael Rotschild
Sally, Sue L                Sue Sally
Rinkel, Michael             Michael Rinkel
Rivel, Nicholas L           Nicholas Rivel
Hurwitz Sr., Susan          Susan Hurwitz
```

The formula I have so far is: =TRIM(PROPER(TRIM(IF(ISERROR(FIND(",",A1,1)),A1,MID(A1,FIND(",",A1,1)+1,IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ",A1,FIND(",",A1,1)+2)),LEN(A1),FIND(" ",A1,FIND(",",A1,1)+2))-FIND(",",A1,1))))&" "&LEFT(A1,IF(ISERROR(FIND(",",A1,1)),LEN(A1),FIND(",",A1,1)-1))))

Its cobbled together from some other formulas I have found, and eliminates middle initials if they are present, but not the Sr. or Jr.'s if they are present.

Comment: What about `Howell III, Thurston` ?

Comment: Sure? Not sure what you mean...

Answer (score 1):

There are so many nuances to parsing names that just as soon as you think you have covered all possibilities, there are new ones coming up. If you keep a User Defined Formula (aka UDF), you can quickly add new coding processes to meet new problems.

```
Public Function fcn_First_Last_Name(sNAM As String)
    Dim sTMP As String, v As Long, vDELs As Variant, vNAMs As Variant
    sTMP = Application.Trim(sNAM)
    vDELs = Array(" Jr.", " Sr.", " III", " II")
    sTMP = Replace(sTMP, Chr(160), Chr(32))
    For v = LBound(vDELs) To UBound(vDELs)
        sTMP = Replace(sTMP, vDELs(v), vbNullString, compare:=vbTextCompare)
    Next v
    If Asc(Mid(sTMP, Len(sTMP) - 1, 1)) = 32 Then sTMP = Trim(Left(sTMP, Len(sTMP) - 1))
    vNAMs = Split(sTMP, Chr(44))
    If CBool(UBound(vNAMs)) Then
        fcn_First_Last_Name = vNAMs(UBound(vNAMs)) & Chr(32) & vNAMs(LBound(vNAMs))
    Else
        fcn_First_Last_Name = vNAMs(UBound(vNAMs))
    End If
End Function
```

That should get you started. It should also prove to be a good learning experience as you add new routines to cover new difficulties.

Once you have that in a VBA code module sheet, use it just like any other worksheet formula. Example:

[image: Name Parsing]

Comment: Thanks Jeeped! I've been learning VBA over the past few months, but am still working 50/50 w/ formulas.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility, but very clunky:

```
=MID(A2,FIND(", ",A2,1)+2,IFERROR((FIND(" ",A2,FIND(", ",A2,1)+2)-4)-FIND(", ",A2,1)+2,LEN(A2)))&" "&IFERROR(LEFT(A2,FIND(" ",LEFT(A2,FIND(", ",A2,1)-1))-1),LEFT(A2,FIND(", ",A2,1)-1))
```